# Find the value in the key in json object

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I stored the jsonvalue in one variable.

```
var result=[{"controlID":"B","currentValue":"5","onChange":"Testing(A,B)","onClick":""}];
```

How to I get the result `Testing(A,B)` based on `OnChange` Key.

Am new of this field

Comment: As your variable `result` is an array you can access value using index. So use `result[0].onChange`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your variable `result` is an array you can access value using index.

```
var data = result[0].onChange;
```

```js
var result=[{"controlID":"B","currentValue":"5","onChange":"Testing(A,B)","onClick":""}];

var data = result[0].onChange;
alert(data)
```